# Is it possible to programmatically launch a Taskpane App within Outlook e.g. from an On-Send App?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm aware that this may not be possible, as suggested here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document

I thought it worth asking as Microsoft apparently do exactly that themselves e.g. for advertising

Comment: The taskpane that is opened for advertising, for example, is not from an add-in. It is part of an unrelated native feature in the client.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. `OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for that. The best what you could do is to add a notification message dynamically from the On-Send event handler with a button to open a task pane.

```
function showInfoBar() {
  Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.addAsync("CommandsKey1", {
    type: Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.InsightMessage,
    message: "Open the Task Pane for more details",
    icon: "Icon.16x16",
    actions: [
      {
        actionText: "Show Task Pane",
        actionType: Office.MailboxEnums.ActionType.ShowTaskPane,
        commandId: "msgComposeOpenPaneButton",
        contextData: "{''}",
      },
    ],
  });
}
```

Comment: Confirming that from Office.js this is the only function that currenlty relates to Taskpanes. (the InsightMessage). A reasonable design may be that on your OnSend Add-in, STOP the send, then display an Insight Message that suggests to the user to open the taskpane to fix whatever it is in their email. Though you should be careful about always stopping the send unless necessary, as that could be annoying to end users

Comment: To suggest new features please do so at the Tech Community page: https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions